# How can I grep for % in a Groovy array?

Tags: groovy

Given the Groovy array below (note the %) :

```
def list = ["H 11 * * * % env=TEST;state=UP"]
```

Is there a way I can check if the array element contains an %?

I've tried various combinations of the Groovy "find", "findAll" and "any" methods but these only match the entire string and not a single character in it.

grep seems to be the solution but when I try something like this:

```
def name = list.grep(~/%/)
println(name)
```

It just prints [].

I would like to test if a % appears anywhere in the array element.

Comment: Many thanks Andre Mota, Fergara and tim_yates for taking the time to answer my question. All your solutions worked perfectly. I would tick all your answers if I could but went for Andre's true/false solution as it best suited my requirement to add some additional code based on whether the array element had a % or not. Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` can be used to filter arrays just like you did. It will return all elements that match the criteria.

The only problem is the regex you've used, should be `~/.*%.*/` instead of `~/%/`.

---

By the way, `findAll` would also work just like grep:

```
list.findAll { s -> s ==~ /.*%.*/ }​
```

The operator `==~` is a matcher for regular expressions.

---

If you simply wanted to get a truthy (true/false), to check if at least one of the elements matches the criteria, `any` would also work:

```
list.any { s -> s ==~ /.*%.*/ }​
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the regular expression to optionally match characters before and after the `%` with `.*` or similar, i.e this should work:

```
list.grep(~/.*%.*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different option.

```
def list = ["H 11 * * * % env=TEST;state=UP"]
def a = list.findAll { it.indexOf('%') }

if (a.size() > 0) {
print "Found: " + a.size()
}
```